# OnTap flutter validar correctamente datos

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy trabajando con un sistemas de `Login`. Tengo dos `TextField`, uno que es `usuario` y el otro `contrasena`. Al momento de presionar el boton <kbd>entrar</kbd>, entra en acción el método `OnTap`, que se encuentra en un `InkWell`:

```
onTap: () {
                      valido=false;
                      if (usuario != null && contrasena != null) {
                        //chequea con contenga texto en usuario y contrasena
                        fetchPost(usuario,
                            contrasena); //fetchPost conecta con la base de datos
                        if (valido==true){
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => menu()),
                          );
                        }else {
                          print('contrase incorrecta');
                        }

                      } else {
                        _showSnackBar();
```

La variable `valido` va a tomar como `true` si se trajeron datos de la base de datos, en caso de que retorne `[]` se le asigna `false`, y se debería de ejecutar `print('contrase incorrecta')`.

Acá dejo el método `fetchPost`:

```
Future<List<Usuario>> fetchPost(String a,b) async {
    print('espere....');
    final response = await http.get ('https://negociodeprueba.000webhostapp.com/DBRemota/wsJSONConsultarCliente.php?usuario=' + a.toString().trim() + '&&contrasena=' + b.toString().trim());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);

    } //LISTADO DE OBJETOS JSON

    var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
    print(datauser);
    if (datauser.toString() != '[]') {
      valido = true;
      print(valido);

    }

  }
```

El problema es que nunca entra al condicional `if (datauser.toString() != '[]')` que se encuentra en el `fetchPost`. Por ende, no avisa que la contraseña es incorrecta. Lo mismo me pasa cuando dejo los campos vacíos. Si dejo los campos vacíos en el primer intento, el método`_showSnackBar();` funciona perfectamente, pero si completo campos y luego los vacío, no se ejecuta.

¿Puede ser que el `fetchPost` tarda en ejecutarse y no alcanza a asignarle el valor a la variable `valido`? Porque el metodo `fetchPost` es `Async`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así es, tal y como dices, estás haciendo una petición asíncrona sin embargo no esperas al resultado para realizar la validación, necesitas usar `async` y `await` de la siguiente manera.

```
    onTap: () async {
        valido=false;
        if (usuario != null && contrasena != null) {
           //chequea con contenga texto en usuario y contrasena
            await fetchPost(usuario,contrasena);
```

Comment: Gracias diego, siempre aprendo de vos ..